# Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650 after upgrading Oracle to 12g

Tags: oracle, kuali

After our Oracle DB was upgraded from 11g to 12g we got the stacktrace below about `Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650`.  How can I resolve this issue?

```
2015-10-26 14:59:36,319 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] u:/d: ERROR org.enhydra.jdbc.xapool - Error Exception in GenericPool:start java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.db.my.edu:1521:sid : Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.db.my.edu:1521:sid : Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:216)
at org.kuali.rice.core.database.RiceXADataSource.getConnection(RiceXADataSource.java:58)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardPooledConnection.<init>(StandardPooledConnection.java:65)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXAConnection.<init>(StandardXAConnection.java:81)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXADataSource.getXAConnection(StandardXADataSource.java:110)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource.create(StandardXAPoolDataSource.java:159)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.GenericPool.getFromPool(GenericPool.java:251)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.GenericPool.checkOut(GenericPool.java:357)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardPoolDataSource.getConnection(StandardPoolDataSource.java:194)
at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardPoolDataSource.getConnection(StandardPoolDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.StatementsForClassImpl.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.StatementsForClassImpl.getPreparedStmt(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.StatementManager.getPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.JdbcAccessImpl.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.RsQueryObject.performQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.RsIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.RsIteratorFactoryImpl.createRsIterator(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getRsIteratorFromQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getIteratorFromQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.QueryReferenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.QueryReferenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.QueryReferenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.DelegatingPersistenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.DelegatingPersistenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springmodules.orm.ojb.PersistenceBrokerTemplate$3.doInPersistenceBroker(PersistenceBrokerTemplate.java:195)
at org.springmodules.orm.ojb.PersistenceBrokerTemplate.execute(PersistenceBrokerTemplate.java:141)
at org.springmodules.orm.ojb.PersistenceBrokerTemplate.executeFind(PersistenceBrokerTemplate.java:162)
at org.springmodules.orm.ojb.PersistenceBrokerTemplate.getCollectionByQuery(PersistenceBrokerTemplate.java:193)
at org.kuali.rice.ksb.messaging.dao.impl.ServiceInfoDAOOjbImpl.findLocallyPublishedServices(ServiceInfoDAOOjbImpl.java:95)
at org.kuali.rice.ksb.messaging.service.impl.ServiceRegistryImpl.findLocallyPublishedServices(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.findLocallyPublishedServices(Unknown Source)
at org.kuali.rice.ksb.messaging.RemotedServiceRegistryImpl.run(RemotedServiceRegistryImpl.java:337)
at org.kuali.rice.ksb.messaging.RemotedServiceRegistryImpl.start(RemotedServiceRegistryImpl.java:391)
at org.kuali.rice.core.lifecycle.ServiceDelegatingLifecycle.start(ServiceDelegatingLifecycle.java:50)
at org.kuali.rice.core.lifecycle.BaseCompositeLifecycle.start(BaseCompositeLifecycle.java:40)
at org.kuali.rice.core.lifecycle.BaseCompositeLifecycle.start(BaseCompositeLifecycle.java:40)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurerBase.start(RiceConfigurerBase.java:106)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurer.start(RiceConfigurer.java:100)
at org.kuali.rice.core.config.RiceConfigurerBase.afterPropertiesSet(RiceConfigurerBase.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:947)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:701)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.kuali.rice.core.web.listener.StandaloneInitializeListener.contextInitialized(StandaloneInitializeListener.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our solution was to upgrade the ojdbc jar to ojdbc14-11.x.x.x from ojdbc14-10.x.x.x.

Comment: I doubt this is a good answer. I opened a service request directly with Oracle and there isn't a version 11 of the ojdbc14.jar: "The "ojdbc14.jar" was only ever available for versions 9i and 10g. This driver was designed for Java 4 ( JDK 1.4) support and is completely obsolete and unsupported. This format does not exist for version 11g"

Comment: @JoeyCote It worked for us.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14/11.2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Check if there exists a version of ojdbc jar already in the jre path. If so then delete this jar as it would be conflicting with the correct version of ojdc from your application. Like in my case it was conflicting with the maven repo path.

Comment: how to do that? I know that from jdk8 it shouldn't be inside jre, but i still cannot how to do this check at runtime

Comment: For me, I was using a Spring Framework application and a different odjbc jar was in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` and that was taken into consideration instead of the one in maven repo

Answer (score 0):

I've used `ojdbc7.jar`. It works fine for me. Here's [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same error after upgrading to Oracle 19c. I was able to resolve the problem with following changes-

1. Replaced ojdbc6.jar with ojdbc8.jar from the Oracle19 client
2. Used these parameters in connection

   Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.put("user", user);
   prop.put("password", pwd);
   prop.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "accepted");
   prop.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "AES256");
   prop.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client","REQUESTED");
   prop.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client", "SHA256");

   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);

After deploying above changes I am able to connect to the database.

Hope this answer helps someone facing similar error.