# Configuring Network Data Encryption and Integrity for Thin JDBC Clients

Tags: java, oracle11g

I want to configuring Network Data Encryption and Integrity for Thin driver.
Vendor said that they have enable encryption for their oracle db.

CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL=REQUIRED
CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES=AES256

I have oracle thin jar (ojdbc7) and I want to fetch data from db using encrypted connection.

```
int level = AnoServices.REQUIRED; 
props.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", 
Service.getLevelString(level)); 
props.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "AES256"); 
props.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client",
Service.getLevelString(level)); 
props.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client", "MD5");
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource(); 
ods.setUser(userId); 
ods.setPassword(password); 
ods.setURL(url); 
ods.setConnectionProperties(props); 
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

I have tried with above code but ending with ORA-12650 error.
Is it possible to do with oracle thin ? 
Can anyone please help........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650 after upgrading Oracle to 12g](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33377846/5221149)

Comment: Show actual code, and full error message.

Comment: See also: [Io exception: Unknown Encryption or Data Integrity algorithm](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1325615?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Do not put code in a comment, where it cannot be formatted. **Edit** the question and clarify it. Delete the comment.